# Form Enabled in FormClosing Event Not Working

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

I'll show you my code first:

```
Private Sub AddProductToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddProductToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Enabled = False
    Dim frmAddProduct As New FormAddProduct
    frmAddProduct.Show()
    frmAddProduct.Owner = Me
End Sub
```

That is my Main Form to call AddProduct form, and this is my FormClosing in AddProduct

```
Private Sub FormAddProduct_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    ButtonReset.PerformClick()
    Lock()
    Me.Owner = Nothing
    Me.Hide()
    Dim frmMainIndex As New FormMainIndex
    frmMainIndex.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

So I have set enabled = false in my main form when it call Add Product form, and enabled = true when I close my Add Product form, but enabled = true won't work.

When I close my Add Product, it's only hide Add Product form but not enabling main form, main form still not enabled. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
Dim frmMainIndex As New FormMainIndex
```

You are instantiating a ***new*** `FormMainIndex`. Whenever you use the [**`New` keyword**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx) you are creating a completely new and independant object. `frmMainIndex` is a completely different form than the first one which opened your `FormAddProduct` form.

Since you've set the `FormAddProduct`'s owner to your `FormMainIndex` form, just set the owner's `Enabled` property to True instead:

```
ButtonReset.PerformClick()
Lock()
Me.Owner.Enabled = True
Me.Owner = Nothing
Me.Hide()
```

Also, your `Me.Hide()` call doesn't make any sense since your form is about to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created a new instance of FormMainIndex, the frmMainIndex.Enabled was applied to this new instance, not the one that created your FormAddProduct. Why don't you show your FormAddProduct as a dialog. like this

```
Dim frmAddProduct As New FormAddProduct
frmAddProduct.ShowDialog(Me)
```